# Adabag package in R

Tags: r, adaboost

I am trying to perform classification using R's adabag package.

The following call works perfectly with R's ada package's ada() function.

```
model<-ada(factor(label)~., data=trainingdata)
```

But when the same training data set is used in the following adabag's function call, it returns an error:

```
model<-boosting(factor(label)~., data=trainingdata)

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , as.character(formula[[2]])) : 
undefined columns selected
```

What this error suggests exactly?

Comment: It suggests that in the dataframe `trainingdata` that there is no column named `factor(label)`.

Comment: Maybe if you have a data frame `trainingdata` you can try `model<-boosting(factor(trainingdata$label)~., data=trainingdata)`

Comment: I suspect the solution might be to perform the factor operation before the boosting call: `trainingdata$label <- factor( trainingdata$label); (bmodel<-boosting(factor(label)~., data=trainingdata) )` . I've noticed that a lot of the 'machine learning' packages either do not have formula interfaces or that they are incompletely implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get exactly that error message when running a minor modification of `boosting`'s first example:

```
> data(iris)
> iris.adaboost <- boosting(factor(Species)~., data=iris, boos=TRUE, mfinal=10)
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , as.character(formula[[2]])) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

So you should try the advice I just gave in a comment (to do the factor()-ing beforehand). The formula interface to `boosting` is not full featured enough to even handle the `factor` function in its parse-tree.